# Windows 7 Network Share Rejecting Password Over WAN

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I'm trying to set up a network share on Windows 7, so that I can access my files over the internet, not just from my local network. I've forwarded ports 445 and 139, and am having a rather strange problem - when I try to connect from within my local network, everything works fine; but when I try to connect using my external IP address, I get prompted for a username and password. I enter my Windows account details, but they get rejected as incorrect!

Answer (score 3):

### Don't Do This!

You should **NOT** share your files over the Internet using SMB, which is Windows' file-sharing protocol.  SMB is only intended to be used on an internal LAN that has a firewall protecting it from the Internet. That firewall should block access to ports 445 and 139 to prevent attacks on SMB over TCP/IP.

This is true even if you use very strong passwords to protect your SMB shares.

The most recent example of why this is a terrible idea is the Wanna Cry attack. This virus was able to [exploit a vulnerability in SMB](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2017/05/smb-exploited-wannacry-use-of-eternalblue.html) that allowed it to copy itself to the remote computer (completely bypassing any passwords that were meant to prevent unauthorized access) and then execute on the machine, taking complete control of it.

A much better idea is to set up a VPN server, then VPN into your network and then access your SMB file share *through* the encrypted VPN connection.